# Getting Multiple Repeat Error when using re.search

Tags: python, regex, email

I have a bunch of emails in .txt files. I want to replace the Subject from email body. Just the context of the subject.

For example: Subject: Re: Who are you doing ? , I am expecting this Subject: Re:.

I have looped over all the .txt files and stored the subject from each email in a list like this.

subject list = ['DID HE REALLY RISE???','Q: Change icons forever???', 'The doctrine of Original Sin' etc.....]

For removing subject from the text files I have written this code:
please note this just a part of code:
`subject_line` = actual `subject` from `subject list` above I mentioned ex:`DID HE REALLY RISE???` or  `Q: Change icons forever???`

`subject` = It's the actual from text file. I want to search of `subject_line` in each line of text file and replace with an empty space `''`

```
    for subject in file_opened:
      if not bool(re.search(subject_line,subject)):
        file_copy.write(subject)

      if bool(re.search(subject_line,subject)):
        subject = re.sub(subject_line,'',subject)
        file_copy.write(subject)
```

But I am getting this errro `error: multiple repeat at position 20`.
I am new to regular expressions. I am sure I am missing some pattern quantifier or something.

Please help me out with this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the subject line:

```
for subject in file_opened:
  if not bool(re.search(re.escape(subject_line), subject)):
    file_copy.write(subject)

  if bool(re.search(subject_line, subject)):
    subject = re.sub(re.escape(subject_line), '', subject)
    file_copy.write(subject)
```

There is a problem with using the following text as a direct regex pattern:

```
DID HE REALLY RISE???
```

The problem is that `?` is a regex *metacharacter*, and has a special meaning.  If you want to search for this literal text, you should be using:

```
DID HE REALLY RISE\?\?\?
```

The `re.escape()` function handles this regex escaping for you.